# Form hide doesn't work in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just started Visual Studio and I tried opening another form using a button and it worked well but the hide code to hide the first form doesn't seem work. Here's my code (Login = form1, Interface = form2):

```
private void login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login login_f = new Login();
        Interface interface_f = new Interface();
        login_f.Hide();
        interface_f.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on:

Exactly what's been written.

1. A button on an existing `Login` form is clicked
2. A new `Login` from is created and stored into `login_f` variable.
3. A new `Interface` from is created and stored into `interface_f` variable.
4. `interface_f` becomes visible, `login_f` form becomes invisible. *The very first form which has been actually clicked stays the same.*

What to do:
`login_f` variable should contain reference to the clicked form. This reference can be retrieved via `this` keyword.

```
private void login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var login_f = this;
        Interface interface_f = new Interface();
        login_f.Hide();
        interface_f.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked. I was searching for a "me" keyword since I remember that's what I used way back on VB 6.0 but couldn't find it.